# How to open two browser window in same cucumber scenario using testcafe?

Tags: javascript, node.js, cucumber, cucumberjs, testcafe

**Testcase: Verify video resume point**

1. Open chrome browser
2. Launch web application
3. Login with an user
4. Play a video
5. Note video played time
6. Close browser
7. Open chrome browser again
8. Launch web application and login with same user
9. Play the same video
10. Video should resume from where the browser was closed

At step 10, Is there a way to automate such that browser opens, closes and again opens in the same cucumber scenario?

I have referred https://github.com/rquellh/testcafe-cucumber
for designing my testcafe-cucumber framework.

Answer (score 1):

TestCafe doesn't support the "close browser" scenario you described. Instead of this, I suggest you [navigate to](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/actions/navigate.html) another URL, then come back to your test URL and check your scenario. However, this approach may not work in a particular video playback implementation. Try it at your own risk.